# `position:absolute` with `bottom:0` is not working with parent having display:flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to fix `div` with class `sidebar` to the bottom of the container, but `position: absolute` with `bottom:0` is not working with a container having `display: flex`.

how to solve that problem?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/zgmg48z1/1/

```css
/*******************page layout**************************/
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.sidebarcontainer{
  width: 250PX;
  /*height: 6000px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.innersidebarcontainer{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 243px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  /*top: 1px;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.mainpage{
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.footer{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #031003;
}
/***************end of pagelayout******************/
.card{
  width: 250px;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
}
.image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sidebarcontainer">
            <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--
    --><div class="mainpage">
        <div class="page">
        <h1>something in the page</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Everything works as it is supposed to. If you give the `sidebar` and all its ascendants a background color you'll see what is wrong. Also the absolute positioned elements relative parent, the `innersidebarcontainer`, is not a flex item, so Flexbox has no direct role in this case

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Can you make a picture of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .sidebarcontainer{
    /*OTHER STUFF*/
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

Explanation here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-14

"This allows the default alignment (or the one specified by align-items) to be overridden for individual flex items."

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sidebar to be at the bottom of the container, you can use `align-self: flex-end` on the sidebar container.

In this case you don't have to use an absolute position on your sidebar. But i'm not sure that's what your trying to do, maybe you need to have a 100% height (of the container) sidebar container and to align bottom the content of the sidebar. If you need that you can set an height on your sidebar container and a relative position. Then use `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` on the sidebar child.

```css
/*******************page layout**************************/
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sidebarcontainer{
  width: 250PX;
  /*height: 6000px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Add align-self: flex-end to the sidebar-container */
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.innersidebarcontainer{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
  width: 243px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  /*top: 1px;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.mainpage{
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.footer{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #031003;
}
/***************end of pagelayout******************/
.card{
  width: 250px;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
}
.image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sidebarcontainer">
            <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--
    --><div class="mainpage">
        <div class="page">
        <h1>something in the page</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact same problem happened to me recently. In my case it wasn't the fault of flex or even the positioning at all in the end, turns out I had another class that was cascading down and also effecting the element's absolute position making it look like my new values weren't working.